# Problema em validação de campo no ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

O campo **Valor Unitário** aceita apenas 3 dígitos após a vírgula. Preciso que ele aceite 4 casas decimais. Gostaria de saber o que pode estar causando essa restrição quanto à formatação deste campo.

O código que tenho implementado é este abaixo:

*ViewModel*

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Valor Unitário é obrigatório.")]
[Column("ValorUnitario")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Display(Name = "Valor unitário *")]
public double ValorUnitario { get; set; }
```

*Front-end*

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.ValorUnitario" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.ValorUnitario" class="form-control" id="valorUn" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ValorUnitario" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

As imagens a seguir mostram o que ocorre quando uso 3 ou mais dígitos após a vírgula.

*Ao inserir 3 dígitos após a vírugula*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Ao inserir 4 ou mais dígitos após a vírgula*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Valor Unitário é obrigatório.")]
[Column("ValorUnitario")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Display(Name = "Valor unitário *")]
public float? ValorUnitario { get; set; }
```

Depois formate:

[Custom numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Veja também:

[ASP.NET MVC data annotation for currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975128/asp-net-mvc-data-annotation-for-currency-format)